# setting and getting values in struts tiles

Tags: java, jsp, struts, apache-tiles

tile definition what i have is :

```
<definition name="test"  path="/t/x/test.jsp"   controllerUrl="/x/t/sController.do">
</definition>
```

this is how i use it in my jsp page :

```
<tr>        
     <td >
         <tiles:insert definition="/test"  flush="true" >
             <tiles:put value="Antony" name="tileTitle" />
         </tiles:insert>    
     </td>      
</tr>
```

and this is how i printed :

```
<% 
    ComponentContext context = ComponentContext.getContext( request );
                if (context != null)
                {
                    String tileTitle = (String)context.getAttribute("tileTitle");

                    if (tileTitle != null)
                    {

    %>

    <tr>
        <td><jsp:include page="/common/tab.jsp" >
             <jsp:param name="TAB" value=" Week '<%= tileTitle%>>' "/>
        </jsp:include>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <%
    }
     %>
```

when i rung the app, i get the following exception `Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" and "value" attributes`

so how do i set he value and pass it to the tiles ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside the tile 'test.jsp' you can use

```
<tiles:useAttribute id="tileTitle" name="tileTitle" />
```

where name is what you specified in calling .jsp and 
id is the one which you can use in your tile.

It can be used in jsp tags as `<%=tileTitle.toString()%>`

or in struts tags by declaring

`<html:hidden property="tileTitle" value="<%= title.toString()%>"/>`